# URL problem w/ code from a django-voting tutorial

Tags: django, django-voting

I'm trying to use the django-voting tutorial from this blog:

http://new.justinlilly.com/blog/2008/nov/04/django-voting-a-brief-tutorial/

to get a simple up/down voting system working on an app of mine. But just like the first commenter from that post, this code in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^(?P[-\w]+)/(?Pup|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object, tip_dict, name="tip-voting"),
)
```

Gives me this error:

```
unknown specifier: ?P[
```

I'm terrible w/ regular expressions, anyone have an idea of how to fix that url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like his blog is mangling the URL. It should probably be:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$', vote_on_object, tip_dict, name="tip-voting"),
```

The pattern being used, from the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), is a named group:

> `(?P<name>...)`
>
> ```
> Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group
> ```
>
> is accessible within the rest of the
>   regular expression via the symbolic
>   group name name. Group names must be
>   valid Python identifiers, and each
>   group name must be defined only once
>   within a regular expression. A
>   symbolic group is also a numbered
>   group, just as if the group were not
>   named. So the group named id in the
>   example below can also be referenced
>   as the numbered group 1.
>
> ```
> For example, if the pattern is `(?P<id>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)`, the group can be
> ```
>
> referenced by its name in arguments to
>   methods of match objects, such as
>   `m.group('id')` or `m.end('id')`, and also
>   by name in the regular expression
>   itself (using `(?P=id)`) and replacement
>   text given to `.sub()` (using `\g<id>`).

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right, I should've noticed that. Working great now, thanks.